# How to properly center align whats inside this table element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to edit [this webpage here](http://www.intervalrelief.com/summary.html).

I am a novice front end developer and am still trying to learn. My coworker created this site by copying a template from another site so thats why all the code is so screwy and unorganized (sorry!).

Basically I would like to center the element near the bottom as shown below:

[image]

And I believe this is the relevant code below, it is on line 263:-

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><div align="center">
          <p><a href="https://www.onlinebusinessbureau.com/Companyrating.cfm?  Company_ID=1843849"><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="80" height="124" id="SealTracker" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="https://www.onlinebusinessbureau.com/SealTracker.swf?Company_ID=1843849" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><embed src="https://www.onlinebusinessbureau.com/SealTracker.swf?Company_ID=1843849" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="80" height="124" name="SealTracker" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object></a><br /><span class="Helvetica12"><<strong></strong></span><img src="images/US_CoC_Logo.png" alt="US Chamber of Commerce"/></p>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
```

From my limited knowledge on tables I understand I should be using something like:

```
style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"
```

I understand the code is a huge mess, that factor along with my limited knowledge on tables is really throwing me off. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: An `object` within an `a` within a `p` within a `div` within a `td`? Why do you need so many elements?

Comment: The table that contains the item in question is set to width 220px, if you set the width to 100% it will work

Comment: Yea its disgusting to look at, I didn't create it myself, I was just asked to edit it. Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that is a mess!   :)

The way to "fix" this is that one of the containing tables is constraining the width. You should change:

```
<table width"220" border="0">
```

To:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

The table that contains the item in question is set to width 220px, if you set the width to 100% it will work

You have

```
<table width="220" border="0">
```

you need

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
```

I would not recommend using tables for layout but it might be a bit late for you since you are already in this mess.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because you have all of your data inside of a div, which cannot be centered using align. So all of your center tags are useless in terms of the positioning of the div.

If you want to keep all of your containers the same, try adding this to the contents of the div tag. style="margin: 0 auto;"

However I would recommend taking out all of the layers of containers they are mostly redundant

Answer (score 0):

Not relevant but please forget to build a website from tables we are not in the 90's anymore. Save the web and your users from it...